# how to use an arrow or pointer instead of the “+” sign in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have created Location map using jvector map its working good.When click country show the plus symbol  want change plus symbol to arrow or vector symbol.How to change ?please help me

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: i find out  my answer  changed css file  now working good.thank you for your comment@rmorrin

Answer (score 2):

i have got answer just changed my css file  cursor to pointer its working good.

```
/* change background color */
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;

      cursor: crosshair;//replace with Pointer:Crosshair

      display:;
    }
```